# How to efficiently create a frequency table of numbers of entries in an array Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I'm trying to implement an efficient way of creating a frequency table in python, with a rather large numpy input array of `~30 million` entries. Currently I am using a `for-loop`, but it's taking far too long.

The input is an ordered `numpy array` of the form

```
Y = np.array([4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9..... etc])
```

And I would like to have an output of the form:

```
Z = {4:3, 5:0, 6:2, 7:1,8:1,9:3..... etc} (as any data type)
```

Currently I am using the following implementation:

```
Z = pd.Series(index = np.arange(Y.min(), Y.max()))

for i in range(Y.min(), Y.max()):
  Z[i] = (Y == i).sum()
```

Is there a quicker way of doing this or a way without `iterating` through a loop? Thanks for helping, and sorry if this has been asked before!

Comment: use [collections.counter?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Do you want the count from the time when you query the dictionary? Or do you want a snapshot at a particular time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this using Counter from collections module. Please see the below code i ran for your test case.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
Y = np.array([4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9,10,5,5,5])
print(Counter(Y))
```

It gave the following output

```
Counter({4: 3, 9: 3, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1, 10: 1})
```

you can easily use this object for further. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think numpy.unique is your solution.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

```
import numpy as np
t = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100000000)
print(np.unique(t, return_counts=True))
```

This takes ~4 seconds for me.
The collections.Counter approach takes ~10 seconds.

But the numpy.unique returns the frequencies in an array and the collections.Counter returns a dictionary. It's up to convenience.

Edit. I cannot comment on other posts so I'll write here that @lomereiters solution is lightning fast (linear) and should be the accepted one.

Comment: I think it's not. Counter is better.

Comment: I saw the "(as any data type)" in the OP and I thought that an array would be acceptable. Is there any other reason why this is not as good?

Comment: `And I would like to have an output of the form:`

Comment: You might be faster to _build_ the array, but might be slower to do lookups... especially if you're doing many.

Answer (score 2):

If your input array `x` is sorted, you can do the following to get the counts in linear time:

```
diff1 = np.diff(x)
# get indices of the elements at which jumps occurred
jumps = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(diff1 > 0)[0] + 1, [len(x)]])
unique_elements = x[jumps[:-1]]
counts = np.diff(jumps)
```